# Access my Fiancee android phone remotely

Tags: remote-control, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access by android phone from web browser and control it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10434/how-do-i-access-by-android-phone-from-web-browser-and-control-it)

I bought Galaxy S3 to my fiancee as a gift but she could not manage it and install APN and contacts and some apps, I am looking for free or commercial software or app, so I could help her managing her phone under her **supervision**.

Thank you guys I have to help her get internet on her phone, so we could use communications apps.

My phone calls bill is really expensive

Answer (score 3):

Try Remote Web Desktop application for android:

[Remote Web Desktop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xdevelop.rm&hl=de)